# I Can't understand the behavior of this async scenario

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm working on an `EventManager` that is responsible for registering some `Subscribers` and notify them when an event is raised.
I want to simulate a loop scenario to find a way to prevent it.Here's the test that I've written :

```
[Test]
public void LoopTest()
{
    var eventManager = new EventManager();
    eventManager.IntroduceEvent("A",typeof(EventArgs));
    eventManager.IntroduceEvent("B", typeof(EventArgs));

    eventManager.Subscribe<EventArgs>("A", (sender, args) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Raise B");
        eventManager.RaiseAsync("B", sender, args);
    });
    eventManager.Subscribe<EventArgs>("B", (sender, args) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Raise A");
        eventManager.RaiseAsync("A", sender, args);
    });

    eventManager.RaiseAsync<EventArgs>("A",null,null).Wait();
}
```

and here's the `async` method :

```
public Task RaiseAsync<T>(string eventName, object sender, T eventArgs)
{
    EnsureEventIsIntroduced(eventName, typeof (T));
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    _subscribers[eventName].Values.ToList()
        .ForEach(
            subscriber =>
                tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ((Action<object, T>) subscriber)(sender, eventArgs))));
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

When I run this test using Resharper test runner I see the following result in output and test passes.

```
Raise B
Raise A
Raise B
Raise A
Raise B
```

Although, I expect that this test should produce an infinite loop . Would you please explain what's going on ? (However the `sync` version of this test produces an infinite loop.)

Comment: Please pay more attention to formatting when posting code. There's no reason why your code should have been indented like it was before I edited it.

Comment: Next, your test doesn't wait for the result of `RaiseAsync` to complete. It should probably be an async test which awaits the result...

Comment: Thanks :) It's a honored to have you code edited by Jon Skeet :)

Comment: Your first call to `RaiseAsync("A",null,null)` will return after the FIRST task completes. While it is returning and the `LoopTest()` method comes to an end, there are 4 more events - but then the infinite loop is *killed*

Comment: @JonSkeet I changed the code to wait for RaiseAsync but still it doesn't produce the loop

Comment: Yes, there's more going on than I first thought - see my answer.

Comment: Shouldn't you be `Assert`ing something in here? 5 events were fired?

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz the problem is I don't know what I should assert at this point :) BTW it's not a unit test I just want to easily run my code (instead of having a console application)

Comment: Based on your comments etc. I'd suggest looking into established event aggregators that are already out there.

Comment: @DanielKelley any recommendations ?

Comment: That would be off-topic for SO :) However, between you and me I previously used the PRISM EA in a WPF application before. I'm sure they are all very good.

Answer (score 2):

There are three reasons you're not seeing an infinite loop.

Firstly, your test isn't waiting for the event to complete. You should change your test to:

```
[Test]
public async Task LoopTest()
{
    ...
    await eventManager.RaiseAsync<EventArgs>("A", null, null);
}
```

Secondly, when you add a subscriber which raises the event again, *that's* not waiting for the event to complete either.

Thirdly, in your `RaiseAsync`, you're only waiting for the tasks which *start new tasks* to complete. You're not waiting for the subscribers themselves to complete.

I'd strongly advise the use of a `foreach` loop - or just `Select` - in your `RaiseAsync` method, by the way. It would be clearer as:

```
var tasks = _subscribers[eventName]
    .Values
    .Cast<Action<object, T>>()
    .Select(subscriber => Task.Run(() => subscriber(sender, eventArgs)))
    .ToList();
```

It's not entirely clear what you actually want to happen though, which makes it hard to provide proper working code. If you want asynchronous event handlers, they should probably be `Func<object, T, Task>` rather than `Action<object, T>`, which you'd subscribe to using async lambdas.

Comment: Hmmm. I've changed the method according to your advise.still the test passes but Resharper test runner indicates an abortion.

Comment: @Beatles1692: My change at the bottom shouldn't change the behaviour, but it makes it clearer. What's still unclear is what you're trying to achieve. You should think *very* carefully about the bigger picture - what sort of event handlers you're allowing to subscribe (synchronous or asynchronous) and what you want `RaiseEvent` to do.

Comment: I am writing this event manager as a backbone for all our components so they can raise and handle events without knowing each other.They should be able to raise events asynchronously so that it won't block other components to raise another event at the same time.Now that you mentioned the big picture maybe I should have a mechanism to prevent raising an event twice before all of its subscribers have their jobs done?

Comment: @Beatles1692: I don't know - is that something you need? Should you effectively have an event queue? Maybe, maybe not... we can explain how your current code behaves, but that's not the same as knowing what it should do.

Comment: Maybe writing an Event Broker from scratch is not as easy as I thought. Thank you for your time and advice :)

Answer (score 2):

After calling `eventManager.RaiseAsync<EventArgs>("A",null,null);` any subsequent call to RaiseAsync will happen from within the eventhandler - and trigger another async task.

Your FIRST task however can now finish, and therefore your call returns and the method comes to an end. While this happens, 4 more events are triggered.

If you would add a Sleep Statement AFTER your first call, you should see way more subsequent async events beeing processed:

```
[Test]
public void LoopTest()
{
    var eventManager = new EventManager();
    eventManager.IntroduceEvent("A",typeof(EventArgs));
    eventManager.IntroduceEvent("B", typeof(EventArgs));

    eventManager.Subscribe<EventArgs>("A", (sender, args) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Raise B");
        eventManager.RaiseAsync("B", sender, args);
    });
    eventManager.Subscribe<EventArgs>("B", (sender, args) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Raise A");
        eventManager.RaiseAsync("A", sender, args);
    });

    eventManager.RaiseAsync<EventArgs>("A",null,null);

    //Wait a little bit to get more async events processed
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

now, the main-thread will be frozen for 1000ms, allowing the independent, asynchronous subtasks to raise and process more events.

On a live environment this would be an infinite loop. Here i assume it is simple the Test-Environment killing all other async-tasks after the TestMethod ends.